# Is there a way to show a cloudflare protected image in flutter?

Tags: flutter, cloudflare

I want to show an image in my app but it is protected by cloudflare. When i try to view it with cached network image cloudflare denies access. Is there a way to do this with cached network image or maybe a webview?

Comment: you can't override the protection!!, you must get authorization token of some kind, look into their API if it exists